# Concurrent Modification Exception in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using Google Analytics for an Android app. The code usually works fine. However in production, the Google Analytics code fails occasionally with a ConcrruentModificationException. Crashlytics is reporting that.

Is that a bug in Google Analytics?

Must I create my own synchronization code to make sure that Google Analytics is only called from a single thread?

```
Fatal Exception: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
   at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:851)
   at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:891)
   at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:890)
   at com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker.zzb(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker.send(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: where are you call the event to be sent to the server? I find it a bit hard for Google not to have taken care of ConcurrentModification especially in a tool like this.

Comment: "where are you call the event to be sent to the server?" I'm not quite sure what you are asking. If you are asking where I the Google Analytics call is made, it's made in my Android app. Some of the calls are made from the UI thread (e.g. Activity.onCreate). Some are done from background threads (e.g. reverse geo coding with Google Maps).

Comment: thats what I am saying. Maybe you are adding something to a Map and then from another thread you are removing it? It is really difficult to see what is wrong because you do not give enough information.

Comment: "Maybe you are adding something to a Map and then from another thread you are removing it?" This is not a general concurrency question. This is specific to Google Analytics. Google Analytics logs user behavior events. These are singular API calls. There is no adding/removing or other way to access the same thing again.

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was? I am running into something very similar and can use some insights. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution, It's happening due to send event of Google Analytics. Multiple threads are using this method of tracker object.

We just need to make it synchronized as:

```
synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
    if (sTracker == null) {
      sTracker = sAnalytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }

    return sTracker;
  }
```

For more details check the links below:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

https://github.com/grazies/analytics-issues/issues/692